# Mouse Cursor Electric Effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash, cursor

What, in your professional opinion, would be the best way to achieve an electric effect stemming from a central location in the center of the screen that is connected to the cursor and follows it around wherever it goes?

Much like the plasma globes...  Only it would be constantly on and follow the cursor wherever it went.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're going to do that, please be kind enough to `history.back()` for the poor user ;)

Comment: Come back when you've actually attempted something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps look at [Canvas Lightning](http://www.somethinghitme.com/projects/canvaslightning/).